# How to get Y by percentage height android?

Tags: android, scrollview, height, percentage, android-nestedscrollview

can you tell me how to scroll to position by percentage of height scrollview?

this code to know percentage if scrolled, but how to get y if percentage is already known?

```
val scrollViewHeight = v.getChildAt(ZERO).bottom - v.height
val getScrollY = v.scrollY
val scrollPosition = getScrollY / scrollViewHeight * 100
Log.i("scrollview", "scroll Percent Y: $scrollPosition")
```

thanks :)